# Choose template option for newfiles in Vim?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim, gvim, options

I have different templates in this directory `~/Documents/Library/` 
like: Template.cpp, normal.cpp, advanced.cpp

Normally I use this:

```
autocmd BufNewFile *.cpp 0r ~/Documents/Library/Template.cpp
```

I want to add **an option "choose template"** for new files that I create via `vim file.cpp` or `vim -p file1.cpp file2.cpp`

1. After triggering `vim file.cpp`, Vim will show me multiple options. After choosing one, Vim will use that template.
2. In case of `vim -p file1.cpp file2.cpp`, I want to choose only one for all tabs.
   Vim will use that template on all tabs.

Is it possible? 
if yes, then please help me make this config :)

Comment: Well, there's `input` or `popup_menu` for making the selection. Then you have to handle `argv()` or `v:argv` (to detect `-p`) in some kind of `VimEnter` autocommand to decide what to do

Answer (score 1):

A rough sketch with lots of bugs, probably. The function names could use some work, too.

```
function Templates(ext) abort
  return glob(printf('~/Documents/Library/**/*.%s', a:ext), v:false, v:true)
endfunction

function ChooseTemplateAll() abort
  const ext = fnamemodify(@%, ':e')
  call popup_menu(Templates(ext), #{callback: 'SelectedTemplate', title: 'template for '.@%})
endfunction

function SelectedTemplate(id, result) abort
  if a:result is# -1
    " didn't choose anything
  else
    execute '0read' Templates(fnamemodify(@%, ':e'))[a:result]
  endif
  next
  call ChooseTemplateAll()
endfunction

function ChooseOneTemplate() abort
  const ext = fnamemodify(@%, ':e')
  call popup_menu(Templates(ext), #{callback: 'SelectedOneTemplate', title: 'template for all files'})
endfunction

function SelectedOneTemplate(id, result) abort
  if a:result is# -1
    " didn't choose anything
  else
    execute 'argdo 0read' Templates(fnamemodify(@%, ':e'))[a:result]
    first
  endif
endfunction

function TryTemplate() abort
  if len(v:argv) >= 2 && index(v:argv, '-p') >= 0
    call ChooseOneTemplate()
  else
    call ChooseTemplateAll()
    rewind
  endif
endfunction

augroup templates
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * call TryTemplate()
augroup END
```

Comment: Could you please make the script foolproof?

Comment: @MegaBang could you please specify what is wrong and what needs improved? It was intended as a sketch for you to adapt to your needs.

Comment: I'm still a noob at this. sorry

Comment: Are you there @d-ben-knoble

Comment: @MegaBang unless you can answer my earlier questions or explain what you mean by "foolproof," I can't do much. But perhaps you can take a crack at it yourself and learn by doing?

Comment: it's not working as expected.

Comment: @MegaBang what does "not working as expected" mean? Details would be the most helpful.

Comment: When creating a file `:e hello.cpp`, these shows up
 `Error detected while processing VimEnter Autocommands for "*"..function TryTemplate: line 5` and `E163: There is only one file to edit`

 then `Error detected while processing VimEnter Autocommands for "*"..function TryTemplate[5]..SelectedTemplate: line 4`  also `E684: List index out of range: 1`

Comment: in terminal, these error shows up `Error detected while processing function SelectedOneTemplate: line 4:` and `E37: No write since last change (add ! to overwrite)`. Though pressing `enter`, the template goes to current file but doesn't apply to all.

Comment: I think for the index out of range, try `:%s/\Va:result]/a:result-1]`

Comment: @MegaBang I'm not sure about the E163 or E37; do you have `hidden` set? I'm also not sure why the autocommand would show up when running `:edit`; it should only run once on startup.

Comment: No, I don't have `hidden` set in my config. And where should I add the code for index out of range?

Comment: @MegaBang sorry, I gave a command to edit the code to fix the out-of-range. It should change the indexing `[a:result]` to `[a:result-1]`. I would have to think more about how to cope with `nohidden`, but maybe adding `:hide` to `:next`/`:argdo`/etc. would help?

Comment: Please do as your time permits.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running GVim you can do

```
:bro r ~/Documents/Library
```

and choose file using the standard GUI dialog.

Comment: used to run GVim on windows, now do all the work in terminal via NeoVim